# Kendo UI Color picker crashes on close when data-bind attribute added

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-observable, kendo-colorpicker

I'm trying to use Kendo UI Color Picker with Kendo binding and run into problem.

Kendo UI Color picker crashes when you click apply button on popup when data-bind attribute added.

When I click on apply button it throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of null
```

You can see example here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  
  <div id="variables">
    <div class="variables-grid">
      <div data-template="variable-template" data-bind="source: variables">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script id="variable-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    # var templateId = getTemplateId(Type); #
    <div class="variable">
        <div data-template="#=templateId#" data-bind="source: this"></div>
    </div>
  </script>
  
  <script id="color-variable-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <input class="k-input" data-bind="value: Value" id="color-picker-#=Id#" name="color-picker-#=Id#" type="color" /><script>
 jQuery(function(){jQuery("\#color-picker-#=Id#").kendoColorPicker({});});
    <\/script>
  </script>
    
</script>


</body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    
    function getTemplateId(typeId) {
      switch(typeId) {
        case 'color':
          return "color-variable-template";
      }
    }
    
    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
      variables: [
        {"Id": "abc-color", "Type": "color", "Name": "Color", "Value": "#ffffff"}
      ]
    });


    kendo.bind($("#variables"), viewModel); 
  </script>
</html>
```

When I remove data-bind attribute it works as should.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like variables isn't created correctly.

[HERE](http://dojo.telerik.com/ojideS) is a Telerik Dojo link with the correction made.

All I did was change

```
<div id="variables">
    <div class="variables-grid">
      <div data-template="variable-template" data-bind="source: variables">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="variables">
  <div class="variables-grid">
    <div>
      <input data-role="colorpicker"
             data-bind="visibile: isVisible,
                        enabled: isEnabled,
                        value: selectedColor,
                        events: { change: onChange}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if that doesn't solve your problem.

[HERE](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/colorpicker/mvvm) is a link to the demo I used to make the correction.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that solution doesn't solve my problem because it changes logic of rendering templates. I need to use different templates for different types of variables.